# Microsoft.AspNet.TestHost.TestServer requires more than one Core/Processor?

Tags: continuous-integration, cpu, dnx, appveyor

Following an [article on strathweb](http://www.strathweb.com/2015/05/integration-testing-asp-net-5-asp-net-mvc-6-applications/), I recently added some integration tests to my DNX project. Locally these run fine (yay for in memory web servers).

However when running the [tests on a VM with only a single core](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/jamescrosswell/commandrouting/build/0.0.13), the integration tests hang indefinitely (and eventually fail because appveyor builds are capped to 60 minutes.

Curiously, when running the [tests on a VM with more than one core](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/FeodorFitsner/commandrouting/build/0.0.6) everything runs fine.

The obvious conclusion is that maybe Microsoft.AspNet.TestHost.TestServer **needs** more than one Core (or at least more than one logical processor). Does anyone have any experience with this to be able to confirm/deny?

Comment: FYI: Katana is the predecessor to DNX applications. You're using DNX/ASP.NET5, not Katana.

Comment: Sharing the test code may help.

Comment: Thanks Tratcher - edited the post to remove Katana. The test code is [here](https://github.com/jamescrosswell/CommandRouting/blob/master/src/Sample.IntegrationTests/Commands/SayHelloTests.cs) - it's an open source project so the code being tested is also in that repo.

Comment: Ah, it's the `.Result` that breaks you, it hangs up the thread on your only core so other threads can't execute. Switch the tests to `public async Task` and use `await`.

Comment: Awesome @Tratcher - that did the trick! Thank you. It's a bit strange that a single core can't handle multiple threads (multithreading predates multicore architectures) but I guess I'd need to do some more reading on async to understand that. Thanks for your help in any case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Tratcher replied as a comment:
xUnit supports async so make your test async and *return task* (otherwise xUnit doesn't know the outcome of your test and it will pass even before it finishes running):

```
 [Fact]
        public async Task Get_hello_should_ignore_bob()
        {
            // Given a sample client
            var client = SampleClient();

            // When I call POST /account/signin
            var value = new StringContent("");
            var response = await client.PostAsync("/account/signin", value);

            // Then the result should be Hello
            string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            result.Should().Be("\"Hello\"");
        }
```

Now that your test is *async*, you can use *await*, instead of calling .Result on the task (which is what caused your issue):

Also, it's worth noting why this happened. [See more about dead-lock and SynchronizationContext](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/the-perfect-recipe-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-ending-up-with-a-deadlock-using-the-c-sharp-5-0-asynchronous-language-features)